# Android Studio 2.2: Use default API 21 Toolbar instead of support library Toolbar?

Tags: android-studio, toolbar

I'm new to Material Design, but all tutorials say ActionBar is deprecated and one should now use Toolbar as the cool new navigation bar of the day.
I configured my app to have API 21 as a minimum requirement, I don't want to use the support library and I really don't care about older Android devices. However, when trying to add a Toolbar in Android Studio 2.2, it insists on adding appcompat-v7 to my project. Isn't Toolbar a native class in API 21 that can be used without any support library? If so, why doesn't it pop up in the Android Studio widget palette?

I browsed Android 21 sources and found Toolbar in android.widget.Toolbar.java. However, in the documentation on developer.android.com the native Toolbar is listed under android.support.design.widget.Toolbar. The documentation also contains android.widget.Toolbar, but that's just a reference to android.support.design.widget.Toolbar.

Can anybody please clarify all this Toolbar mess to me? Thank you.

Comment: are you trying to use the last widget in list called 'Toolbar' in widget palette?

Comment: Yes, there is no other Toolbar widget in my palette.
As a workaround I manually added the toolbar to the XML, but that kinda beats the purpose of the GUI editor. Would like to remove all that support library crap from Android Studio when setting the appropriate minimum API version.

Comment: ...and now I can't even add widgets to the toolbar via GUI editor. Have to also add them manually to the XML, then they appear in the editor. I don't get it, what's the purpose of the GUI editor? It's totally useless.

Comment: I and developers that I know don't use GUI editor ;)

Comment: Yawn. So obviously there's no vi plugin yet to generate useful stackoverflow replies...